# Windows Store App update GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How to update the contents of GridView. ie initially I bind data to GridView & once I have updated the database I have to clear the existing items and bind updated items.

Comment: for that please use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx)...

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: please go though this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780627.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are already binding the `GridView`? In this case you have two options:

1. You can bind it to an `ObservableCollection` which will notify the UI when it changes. This means you can just clear this collection to remove the old items and then add the new updated items to it.
2. Alternatively you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class containing the collection you are binding the `GridView` to, and raise `PropertyChanged` when you replace the collection containing the old items with a new collection containing the updated items.

It would be easier to help you if you would post some code showing what you're currently doing.